# Shared object in Linux without symbol interposition, -fno-semantic-interposition error

Tags: shared-libraries

Shared objects (*.so) in Unix-like systems are inefficient because of the symbol interposition: Every access to a global variable inside the .so needs a GOT lookup, and every call from one function to another inside the .so needs a PLT lookup. I was therefore happy to see that gcc version 5.1 has added the option -fno-semantic-interposition. However, when I try to make a .so where one function calls another without using a PLT, I get the error message:

> relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `functionname' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I expected the option -fno-semantic-interposition to eliminate this error message, but it doesn't. -mcmodel=large doesn't help either.
The reference to the function is indeed position-independent, which the error message actually confirms (R_X86_64_PC32 means PC-relative 32-bit relocation in 64-bit mode). -fPIC does not really mean position-independent, as the name would imply, it actually means use GOT and PLT.

I cannot use `__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))` because the called function and the caller are compiled in seperate files (caller is in C++, called function is in assembly).

I tried to make an assembly listing to see what the option -fno-semantic-interposition does. I found out that it makes a reference to a local alias when one function calls another in the same file, but it still uses a PLT when calling a function in another file.

(g++ version is 5.2.1 Ubuntu, 64-bit mode).

Is there a way to make the linker accept a cross-reference inside a .so without the GOT/PLT lookup?

Comment: Future readers: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849308/x86-64-is-it-possible-to-in-line-substitute-plt-got-references for trying to avoid the PLT when calling across shared-object boundaries.  (e.g. from a program into a library).  The best that seems to be possible is replacing indirection through the PLT with an indirect `call` through a pointer from the non-lazy GOT.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to make the linker accept a cross-reference inside a .so without the GOT/PLT lookup?

Yes: `attribute((visibility("hidden")))` is exactly the way to do it.

> I cannot use attribute((visibility ("hidden"))) because the called function and the caller are compiled in seperate files

You are confused: `visibility("hidden")` means that the symbol will not be exported from the shared library, when it is finally linked. But the symbol is *global* and *visible* across multiple translation units before that final link.

Proof:

```
$ cat t1.c
extern int foo() __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));

int main() { return foo(); }
$ cat t2.c
int foo() __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));
int foo() { return 42; }
$ gcc -c -fPIC t1.c t2.c
$ gcc -shared t1.o t2.o -o t.so
$ nm -D t.so | grep foo
$
```

> I tried to make an assembly listing to see what the option -fno-semantic-interposition does. I found out that it makes a reference to a local alias when one function calls another in the same file, but it still uses a PLT when calling a function in another file.

If you read the [discussion](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/350825/) in gcc-patches, you'll see that the `-fno-semantic-interposition` is about allowing inlining of possibly interposable functions, not about the way they are actually called when not inlined.

Comment: As a side note, some other compilers (LLVM) do semantic interposition by default (thus breaking ELF semantics but shining in benchmarks).