# how do I add new methods to a class in the standard library

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to extend the `std::fstream` class from the `<fstream>` header. I plan to add a couple functions like `std::fsteam create(path)`, `std::vector<std::string> read_lines(path)`, etc.

What Im asking is pretty simple. Instead of creating a whole new class, I want to be able to just simply add the methods in another file and then just make `std::fstream` objects and use those new methods.

I have two files. `file_helper.hh` where I will declare the methods, and `file_helper.cc` where I will define them and link them to my `main.cc` file.

So, what do I write within `file_helper.hh` to add these new methods to `std::fstream` if possible? Is it even possible?

Comment: The c++ language does not support adding methods to a class without modifying it. Inheriting a standard library class is also not a good idea. You could add free functions getting the `fstream` by reference as a parameter.

Comment: **You can't add member to any class(after its definition) let alone standard defined class.**

Comment: Unclear to me what you are trying to achieve... For instance, what would the purpose of your so-called `create` method be? Compared to e.g. the constructor?

Comment: You cannot, and also the STL classes (in general) are also not designed to be inherited from, I think streams are an exception.

Comment: Except for a very few exceptions, you enter the land of UB if you try to use a class in the Standard Library as a base class, and add some new functionality to it. The best thing to do is to encapsulate a Standard Library object in a class of your own, and add the new functions there. Use wrappers to expose the methods from the Standard Library object that you want to use as part of the interface of your class.

Comment: @tbxfreeware streams have virtual destructors so they are kind of the exception. Still needs some special care and there are quite a few examples around online on how to do that

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer: Thanks. I did not know that. Maybe it is fine, but the idea still rubs me the wrong way!

Comment: @tbxfreeware Don't worry it rubs me too. Inheritance is overused. And I would still prefer aggregation or freestanding functions.

Comment: read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809463/is-there-any-advantage-to-implementing-functions-as-free-functions-rather-than-m

Comment: @PepijnKramer the base classes of `fstream` have protected members and are supposed to be inherited, but afaik the only reason that `fstream` has a virtual destructor is because it does inherit it. I suppose `fstream` itself could be `final`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I wish they did that (add final). But I it can't be retrofitted now.

Comment: @Atmo i probably shouldnt have included that in my post. Basically im gonna have `create` and `delete` in a case where i might have to delete a file and then later on create it again, so a constructor would only work for the first time. But with a create function i can keep creating and deleting on the same object.

Comment: @tbxfreeware could you expand on this? sounds like a pretty interesting workaround.

Comment: _Encapsulation_, in your case, would mean having an `fstream` object as a private member of some class of your own, say `my_fstream`. You could write short _wrapper functions_ to expose the functions of `fstream` that you want to be available to users of `my_fstream`. So, for example, `my_fstream::open` would call `std::fstream::open`. Finally, you could _extend_ `fstream`, by adding  your own functions, such as `read_lines`, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do that in C++ is to add your own free-standing functions with the functionality you want:

```
// stdex.h
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

namespace stdex 
{
    std::vector<std::string> read_lines(std::ifstream& self);
}
```

And then you just use them as you would any function:

```
// main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "stdex.h"

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file{"foobar.txt"};
    for (const auto& line : stdex::read_lines(file)) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: all this does is take the object as a parameter which isnt what i was trying to do, i wanted to be able to use it like this `std::fstream my_file("foobar.txt");       std::cout << my_file.read_lines()[4];` but ive been told above that its not possible.

Comment: @itsrxmmy How is that different/better than `std::cout << read_lines(my_file)[4];` ?

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it that way. I already know how to put parameters inside of a function, which is basically all this solution is. Not that its different or better, I just like to play around with C++ and see where certain lines are drawn and how many workarounds there are.

Comment: @itsrxmmy I am showing you how what you're trying to achieve is done in C++ idiomatically. If your only argument is "I want this syntax specifically", then I can't help you with that.

Comment: No problem then. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing would look something like below. Note though:

- The functions you've suggested both take a *path* parameter. Having to create an instance of your `fstream` to be able to call `create(path)` or `read_lines(path)` doesn't make sense. These functions would be much better as free functions.

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class myfstream : public std::fstream { // inherit from std::fstream
public:
    // make the fstream constructors and assignment operators available
    using std::fstream::fstream;
    using std::fstream::operator=;

    // example implementations of your member functions:
    std::fstream create(std::filesystem::path path) const {
        return {path, std::ios::out};
    }

    std::vector<std::string> read_lines(std::filesystem::path path) const {
        std::vector<std::string> rv(1);
        if (std::ifstream is(path); is) {
            for (; std::getline(is, rv.back()); rv.emplace_back()) {}
        }
        rv.resize(rv.size() - 1);
        return rv;
    }
};
```