# Why does `-fno-plt` not work when compiling/linking assembly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, executable, elf, dynamic-linking

I am interested in compiling / linking an assembly project whose shared library function calls bypass the PLT (use the GOT directly). I Tried using `-fno-plt` but the resulting library calls still go through the PLT.

##### Questions

I am wondering:

1. Why does the `-fno-plt` argument not work when compiling assembly?
2. Is there a way to compile assembly so that shared library function calls bypass the PLT?

##### Assembly PLT Bypass with `-fno-plt` NOT Working.

Using the simplest example:

```
    .global main
    .text
main:
    callq   exit
```

When compiled with:

```
gcc -fno-plt test0.S -o test0
```

Produces the following for `main`:

```
0000000000001139 <main>:
    1139:   e8 f2 fe ff ff          callq  1030 <exit@plt>
    113e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Which is calling exit through the PLT.

##### C PLT Bypass with `-fno-plt` Working

Alternatively the same code in C:

```
extern void exit(int);
int main() {
    exit(0);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -O2 -fno-plt  test1.c -o test1
```

Gets the following for `main`:

```
0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1044:   50                      push   %rax
    1045:   58                      pop    %rax
    1046:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
    1048:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
    104c:   ff 15 96 2f 00 00       callq  *0x2f96(%rip)        # 3fe8 <exit@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    1052:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    1059:   00 00 00 
    105c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Which correctly bypasses the PLT for the call to `exit`.

Comment: If you use `gcc -S` you will see what the compiler generates to make it work. TL;DR: `call *exit@GOTPCREL(%rip)`. Note that `-fno-plt` only affects code generation it is not needed for your assembly.

Comment: `-fno-plt` has zero effect on the assembler or linker behaviour, only on the C->asm translation step which doesn't happen when you give GCC a `.s` file.  GCC code-gen options won't re-write your asm.  Same reason why "recompile with -fPIC" error messages only apply to object files generated from C, not hand-written asm.  ([32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427))

Comment: Also related: [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126328) mentions the AT&T syntax for it way down in the last section, about relocations that are relaxable or not.  [x86\_64: Is it possible to "in-line substitute" PLT/GOT references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10849308) shows the compiler-generated asm and talks about `-fno-plt`, but maybe not an exact duplicate, IDK.  Maybe of that and one about how "recompile with `-fPIC`" doesn't mean that option will fix asm that uses 32-bit abs addr modes.